# Definite If Statement

Tags: java

I'm learning how to program in java its my first ever language. 
I have been looking around for a *Definite* answer to the if statements. Are the if statements loops? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: jus google it..........u will get 1000's of good answers for it.

Comment: All you need to know about control flow statements is in [the official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html): *This section describes the decision-making statements (if-then, if-then-else, switch), the looping statements (for, while, do-while), and the branching statements (break, continue, return) supported by the Java programming language.*

Comment: alternative [tutorials](http://netbeans.org/kb/articles/learn-java.html)

Comment: @andy I did and its always a "depends", thats why I was hoping a java expert might clarify this, thanks for -1.

Comment: @Mag, post a link to the page that says it depends.

Comment: @assylias, mb21 Thank you will bookmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, no, if statements are not loops.

I suggest you bookmark this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Comment: Thank you, that was the answer I was looking for.